# awk: Group by and then Sort by sub strings of a string

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, awk, substring

Assuming we have following files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      120 Aug 17 18:27 A.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      155 May 12 12:28 A.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      155 May 10 21:14 A.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user group      700 Aug 15 17:05 B.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user group       59 Aug 15 10:02 B.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      180 Aug 15 09:38 B.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      200 Jul  2 17:09 C.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group     4059 Aug  9 13:58 D.txt
```

Considering only HH:MM in timestamp (ie ignoring date/day part of timestamp), I want to sort this listing to pick maximum and minimum timestamp for each file name.
So we want to group by last column and get min & max HH:MM.
Please assume that filename duplicates are allowed in my input data.
In awk code, I particularly got stuck to group by and then sort by HH first and then MM. 
Output we are expecting is in format:

```
Filename | Min HHMM | Max HHMM
A.txt 12:28 21:14 
C.txt 17:09 17:09
```

..
(or any other output format giving this details is good)
Can you please help..TIA

Comment: Thanks  @John1024 for sharing beautiful code.. This was my first lesson with array usage in awk. and helped me to build nice concepts .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk '{if ($8<min[$9] || !min[$9])min[$9]=$8; if ($8>max[$9])max[$9]=$8} END{for (f in min)print f,min[f],max[f]}' file | sort
```

#### Example

```
$ cat file
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      120 Aug 17 18:27 A.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      155 May 12 12:28 A.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      155 May 10 21:14 A.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user group      700 Aug 15 17:05 B.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user group       59 Aug 15 10:02 B.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      180 Aug 15 09:38 B.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group      200 Jul  2 17:09 C.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group     4059 Aug  9 13:58 D.txt
$ awk '{if ($8<min[$9] || !min[$9])min[$9]=$8; if ($8>max[$9])max[$9]=$8} END{for (f in min)print f,min[f],max[f]}' file | sort
A.txt 12:28 21:14
B.txt 09:38 17:05
C.txt 17:09 17:09
D.txt 13:58 13:58
```

#### Warning

Your input looks like it was produced by `ls`.   **If** that is so, be aware that the output of `ls` has a myriad of peculiarities and compatibility issues.  The authors of `ls` recommend against parsing the output of `ls`.

#### How the code works

awk implicitly loops over every line of input.  This code uses two associative arrays.  `min` keeps track of the minimum time for each file name.  `max` keeps track of the maximum.

- `if ($8<min[$9] || !min[$9])min[$9]=$8`

  This updates `min` if the time, `$8`, in the time for the current line is less than the previously seen time for this filename, `$9`.
- `if ($8>max[$9])max[$9]=$8`

  This updates `max` if the time, `$8`, in the time for the current line is greater than the previously seen time for this filename, `$9`.
- `END{for (f in min)print f,min[f],max[f]}`

  This prints out the results for each file name.
- `sort`

  This sorts the output into a cosmetically pleasing form.

Answer (score 1):

similar `awk`

```
$ awk         '{k=$9;v=$8}           # set key (k), value (v)
    !(k in min){min[k]=max[k]=v}     # initial value for min/max
       min[k]>v{min[k]=v}            # set min
       max[k]<v{max[k]=v}            # set max
            END{print "Filename | Min HHMM | Max HHMM"; 
                for(k in min) print k,min[k],max[k] | "sort"}' file

Filename | Min HHMM | Max HHMM
A.txt 12:28 21:14
B.txt 09:38 17:05
C.txt 17:09 17:09
D.txt 13:58 13:58
```

note that printing header and piping data to sort in awk keeps the header in the first line.

Comment: Just beat me to it, +1 for isolating the key and value assignments and explicit seeding with first values read.

Comment: Thanks  @karakfa for sharing beautiful code.. This was my first lesson with array usage in awk. and helped me to build nice concepts .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat > test.awk
BEGIN {
    min["\x00""Filename"]="Min_HHMM"OFS"Max_HHMM" # set header in min[], preceded by NUL
}                                                 # to place on top when ordering (HACK)
!($9 in min)||min[$9]>$8 {                        # if candidate smaller than current min
    min[$9]=$8                                    # set new min
}
max[$9]<$8 {
    max[$9]=$8                                    # set new max
} 
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"          # set array scanning order for for loop
    for(i in min) 
        print i,min[i],max[i]
}
$ awk -f test.awk file
Filename Min_HHMM Max_HHMM
A.txt 12:28 21:14
B.txt 09:38 17:05
C.txt 17:09 17:09
D.txt 13:58 13:58
```

The `BEGIN` hack can be replaced by a static `print` in the beginning of `END` block:

```
print "Filename"OFS"Min_HHMM"OFS"Max_HHMM";
```